# Copas and iterators using coroutines

Tags: sockets, lua, iterator, coroutine

I am trying to adapt [nrk/redis-lua](https://github.com/nrk/redis-lua) to use [copas](https://github.com/keplerproject/copas/). At first, it seemed easy to me (at least for commands like `get`, `set`): just wrap the client using `copas.wrap()`.

It does not work, because calls to `receive` are used within iterators using coroutines. The example below shows what happens:

```
local copas  = require "copas"
local socket = require "socket"

local function iterate (x)
  local client = socket.tcp ()
  client:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
  client:settimeout (0)
  client = copas.wrap (client)
  return coroutine.wrap (function ()
    for k, v in pairs (x) do
      client:receive "*l"
      coroutine.yield (k, v)
    end
    client:close ()
  end)
end

local data = {}
for i = 1, 2 do
  data [i] = i
end

local function worker ()
  local id = coroutine.running ()
  for k, v in iterate (data) do
    print (id, k, v)
  end
end

copas.addthread (worker)
copas.addthread (worker)

copas.loop ()
```

The output is:

```
thread: 0x1b31990   tcp{client}: 0x1b31e48  table: 0x1b2eac0
thread: 0x1b31990   tcp{client}: 0x1b31e48  table: 0x1b2eac0
...
```

First question: i had to put the `client:settimeout (0)`, otherwise the call to `client:receive` was blocking. But it creates an active wait... it there a better way?

Second question: is there a way to fix the problem of yielding within the iterator? i can rewrite the iterator as a closure to avoid using a coroutine, but is there a less intrusive way of solving the problem?

Comment: I'm confused a bit as to what you are trying to do. Saying "adapt nrk/redis-lua" doesn't help me much. Are you trying to send several requests to redis in parallel?

Comment: Yes, i would like -- if possible -- to be able to run commands in several copas threads. To do that, i tried to edit the redis-lua code to wrap the client socket. Even if this worked, it is not sufficient, as we must also ensure that results are read in the same order as requests are sent. But this is another problem...